# slow reading barcode scanner (hid mode)

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am currently implementing an application for scanning barcode codes. The scan is handled by and external barcode reader, which is connected via USB with HID protocol (if an EditText is focused, the code is printed on the EditText ,like a keyboard). The problem is that the reading of the data is very slow.

I am testing it on my laptop, so the barcode reader is connected from USB port.
If I focus an EditText on a random laptop program (browser, notes, microsoft word, ...), the scan is basically instant. If i use the app from the emulator, it take nearly 2/3 sec to print all the data, and sometime it also print wrong data (instead on the pc never fail).

This is the code

```
200002300168’200002400252’200002700224’200002800280’200101700140’200044500140’200045000140’200045100077’200200100014’200200200035’200200300025’200200400043’200200500053’200200600033’200200700116’200200800033’200200900055’200201000051’200201100011’200201200169’200201300170’200201400531’200201500641’200201600010’200201700171’
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Isn't the number within 1 second if you enter 325 characters faster than enough? Rather, it's too fast, so the processing of the application can't keep up and data is lost. 
Since HID is a human keyboard input emulation, it would be okay if each character is notified as fast as a human can operate the keyboard.

Comment: It seems that you can adjust the interval between the characters notified by the setting barcode, so please try it.